# Using the "help" method in the immutable SCOPT (Scala) OptionParser (2.0.1)

Tags: scala, scopt

I am trying to use the new immutable `OptionParser` in the Scala [scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) 2.0.1 library. Since `OptionParser` takes a generic type and the help method already defines an action that returns  `Unit`, I am getting a compile-time error:

```
case class Config(directory: String = null)

val parser = new OptionParser[Config]() {
  def options = Seq(
    opt("d", "directory", "directory containing the files to be processed") {
      (value: String,  config: Config) => config.copy(directory = value)
    },
    help("?", "help", "Show a usage message and exit"))
}

error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : scopt.generic.FlagOptionDefinition[Nothing]
[INFO]  required: scopt.generic.OptionDefinition[Config]
[INFO] Note: Nothing <: Config, but class OptionDefinition is invariant in type C.
```

How can I include a "help" option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there seems to be an error in the library, where one of the overloaded methods of `opt` takes a type parameter `C` which it shouldn't -- at least from what I can tell. It should just take `C` from the class. Anyway, although you use that call, I guess Scala still correctly infers that this `C` is the same as the class's `C` (`Config`).

The problem seems to be that `help` is completely useless -- it gives you `FlagOptionDefinition[Nothing]` because its `action: => C` implementation is `{this.showUsage; exit}`.

I think that the `OptionParser` class needs fixing...

You could write your own `help` method that enforces the `C` type parameter:

```
def help2(shortopt: String, longopt: String, description: String) =
  new FlagOptionDefinition[C](Some(shortopt), longopt, description, 
    { this.showUsage; exit })
```